# What's this statistics-looking icon on my TouchBar?

Tags: touch-bar

I've just discovered this icon on my MacBook Pro's TouchBar:

[image: icon]

Looks like some sort of statistics, or so? It only appears occasionally. Tapping on it I get this slider:

[image: slider]

This doesn't do anything though. When sliding I get a "0:00" count next to it and nothing happens. What is this supposed to do?

<sub>Looks like I'm also unable to take TouchBar screenshots via ⌘+⇧+6 for some reason.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you watching a video in Safari? That slider is telling you that you're watching a video in the app displayed in the icon, scrubbing on that slider scrub the video you're playing. Or if you're not watching a video, it might just be a bug. Try refreshing the Control Strip by going into activity monitor and find the process "Control Strip" and quit that process(it won't do any harm, your touch bar will blink once).

<sub>P.S. As for taking screenshot of the touch bar you need 10.12.2 beta.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the information, I was suspecting something like that. Either it's a bug, or some website has some hidden video content… What a bizarre icon though.

Comment: You are going where no man has gone before

Comment: PS: It also appears when playing something in iTunes, and there it's actually functional. I wonder when and why it appears for Safari…